# Making a dynamic table display limited results with an option to expand

Tags: jquery, html-table, show-hide

I have the following HTML that I can't directly edit as it is being dynamically generated:

```
<table class="v65-productDisplay" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

It shouldn't matter what's inside the TR (I don't think) so I left all that stuff out.
This code block comprises 1 product:

```
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row">
<tr>
```

So basically I would like to use jQuery to display only 4 of these products and have a button to expand/show the rest of them. I am thoroughly confused and don't know where to start. I tried finding each 4 of the TRs, wrapping them in a div, then trying to show/hide them but it screwed up my layout and didn't work at all. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Using this now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var hiddenElements = $('.v65-productDisplay tr:gt(7)').hide();

if (hiddenElements.size() > 0) {
  var showCaption = '<b>View </b>' + hiddenElements.size() + '<b> More Products</b>';
  $('.v65-productDisplay').append(
      $('<li id="toggler">' + showCaption + '</li>')
          .toggle(
              function() { 
                  hiddenElements.show();
                  $(this).html('<b>Collapse</b>');
              }, 
              function() { 
                  hiddenElements.hide();
                  $(this).text(showCaption);
              }
          )
  );
 }
 });
</script>
```

Works perfectly except in the display text of "Show x more Products" it is counting every TR. So instead of saying "1 More Product" it is saying "4 More Products". How can I edit this to display that text correctly?

Comment: can youshow somenthing you've tryed to do?

Comment: See my post please, I found something that is working I just need a small edit:

Answer (score 1):

you forgot about `</tr>` ending tags i think that is causing layout broking.

then if you really need to use a `<table>` i suggest you to put at first 4 `<tr>` a same class i like to use like `'<tr class="show">'` then add new class to the others `<tr class="toggle">`,
create a `<a id="toggle"></a>`

in css file add `tr.toggle{display:none;}`

then in js do:

```
$('a#toggle').live('click',function(){
$('tr.toggle').slideToggle('slow');// you can try also toggle() instead of slideToggle(), i personally preferr slideToggle() ... as you wish :)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function hideProducts(numberToRemain){  
    var rows = $('.v65-productDisplay tr');
    rows.hide();
    for(int i = 0; i < numberToRemain; i++){
        $(rows[i]).show();
    }
}
function showProducts(){
    $('.v65-productDisplay tr').show();
}
```

Then call hideproducts on the document ready event.